# error datasource when bind to girdview

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider

I have a `gridview` and I am trying bind data:

```
string id = Request.QueryString["uid"].ToString();

MembershipUser u = Membership.GetUser(new Guid(id)); 

GridView1.DataSource = Membership.GetUser(u.ProviderUserKey); 

GridView1.DataBind();
```

and I receive a error :

```
Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource,
IEnumerable, or IDataSource.
```

but I tried:

```
GridView1.DataSource = Membership.GetAllUsers();
```

code above ok

How I can bind data to `gridview` by a `ProviderUserKey` like a string

Comment: this is return type error.Don't use an it as this only contains object references. Instead, return a generic List of your object

Answer (score 0):

```
GridView1.DataSource = Membership.GetAllUsers();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Must Work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy8swhya.aspx

Check you syntax you have no "**s**" letter at the end.

Membership.GetAllUser **s** ();